# How to suppress, VS detects EXE is not in synch with Custom File so give Stop Debugging error box during Edit& Continue

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-debugging, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm simulating custom debugger with Edit and Continue through VSExtension, so during live debug session, I'm programmatically using Envdte, triggering MSBuild ,compile to generate .obj file which I will manually patch in exe.

To handle Edit&Continue, I've added my CustomFile as well as its conversion output file (MyFile.xyz, MyFile.cpp) to vcxproj, so that changes in cpp file is detected by build system and can be taken care by Edit & Continue.

But automatic VS Edit & Continue is not working, Even manually while blocking on debug breakpoint and programmatically triggering MSBuild is also not working.
As in Both cases VS detects EXE is not in synch with Custom File so give Stop Debugging error box.

custom file is out of sync with program database "Edit and Continue : error : The dependency information for 'test.xyz' in the state (.idb) file(s) '' is out of sync with the Program Database (.pdb) file 'C:\Projects\TestProj.pdb' for 'TestProj.exe'.

CodeDebugging-EditNContinue-error
[image]
And for Error2 somehow VS detection has to be suppressed to continue debugging. Or File's state in .iDB  can be updated for synch in .pdb, but How?

Comment: what is the edit&continue you mean? VS feature or this extension? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreasFurster.pause-edit-and-continue